# Sample mean is not normally distributed for simulation in R

Tags: r, statistics, simulation

I have run two commands in R, which should give sampling distributions of means:

`hist(apply(matrix(runif(10000, max=5), nrow=1000), 1, mean))`, which gives:

[image: Fewer repetitions]

and `hist(apply(matrix(runif(10000, max=5), nrow=10000), 1, mean))`, which gives:

[image: More repetitions]

What went wrong with the second graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the results of

```
m <- matrix(runif(10000, max=5), nrow=10000)
dim(m)
## [1] 10000 1
```

You've created a matrix with 10,000 rows and **only one column**.  Taking the mean of each row is the same as taking just taking the value in each row.  The sampling distribution of the means of single values is the same as the original uniform distribution.